# In C++, how does the expression, "*pointer++" work?

Tags: c++, pointers, operators

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int value = 1, *pointer;
    pointer = &value;
    cout << *pointer++ << endl;
    cout << *pointer << endl;
}
```

Why does the `++` operator not increment `value`?

Comment: @the_drow: I don't think so.  Well-written code would use parentheses here to make the intent clear to both the compiler and other programmers.

Comment: As it happens, this already is in the comp.lang.c FAQ. See my answer for a link.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: And how often do you see code like this? I've seen it before. An FAQ should contain stuff that you shouldn't do and should advise against it.

Comment: @aix: Yes but there is an faq tag for c++ in stackoverflow as well.

Comment: @the_drow: I'd vote against putting this into the [FAQ tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++-faq), because I think it's not general enough for this. If this was a question about operator precedence, with `*p++` as one example, I'd agree.

Comment: @Ben: `while(*p++)` is one of the very classics of C, and since K&R set this into stone forty years ago nobody has written it with parentheses.

Comment: @aix: @the_drow was referring to this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/68647/setting-up-a-faq-for-the-c-tag

Comment: @the_drow: Yes, that's a subtlely different question ("Where in expressions should I use parentheses?"), and one which I think is a reasonable FAQ.  And the answer should stress that code should be readable both by the compiler and by other programmers, some of whom may work routinely in other languages.

Comment: Two against one. Very well. I still think that it is more likely that you'd gather such questions one by one. Is there a general question about operator precedence in stackoverflow already?

Comment: @sbi: `char* strcpy(dst, src) char *dst, *src; { ... }` is classic K&R as well, but I sure wouldn't recommend it to anyone.

Comment: @Ben: No, I wouldn't. But that had its syntax changed about, what?, 20 or 30 years ago? The classic and very expressive `while(*p++)` is more about style, and (arguably) this style is what C is famous for.

Comment: @Ben: And I don't think "Where in expressions should I use parentheses?" would be a good FAQ entry, since there's almost nothing two programmers could agree about.

Comment: @sbi: An answer would need to cover operator precedence, should discuss macro arguments, and I think it would also be good to highlight precedence differences between languages, which are potential sources of confusion.  Certainly not everyone might want to establish that as their style guideline, but "no parentheses are needed for operators which have consistent precedence across all (infix) programming languages" is at least an objective rule, and I've never had any complaints about code that follows it.  The days of knowing a single language being acceptable for programmers are long gone.

Comment: @Ben. That sounds like a very good FAQ entry. Are you going to write it? `:)`

Comment: @Ben: I can't shed the feeling you have been ducking away from this one! `:)`

Comment: @sbi: umm, I guess it would look like that.  It's not that I don't want to write it, cause I do.  I'm just in the middle of other things right now.

Comment: @Ben: Note the smiley. (I wasn't trying to peck on you. It's just that this FAQ thing is some kind of pet project of mine.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Post-increment (`++`) has higher precedence than dereference (`*`).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) This means that the `++` binds to `pointer` rather than `*pointer`.

See [C FAQ 4.3](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/unopprec2.html) and references therein.

Comment: But what that does that mean.

Comment: Higher precedence means it goes before, so the pointer is increased by sizeof(*pointer), and as it is a postfix operator it returns the old pointer. Then the * operator retrieves the contents the old pointer pointed to. (ofcourse optimizer might change the order of operations to get the same result faster)

Answer (score 7):

Ok, everybody has explained the binding of the parameters.
But nobody mentioned what it means.

```
int    data[1,2,3,4,5];

int*   pointer = data;

std::cout << *pointer++ << std::endl;
std::cout << *pointer   << std::endl;
```

As mentioned the ++ operator has a higher priority and thus binds tighter than the * operator. So the expressions is equivalent too:

```
std::cout << *(pointer++) << std::endl;
std::cout << *pointer << std::endl;
```

But the operator ++ is the postfix version. This means the pointer is incremented but the result of the operation returns the original value for use by the * operator. Thus we can modify the statement as follows;

```
std::cout << *pointer << std::endl;
pointer++;
std::cout << *pointer << std::endl;
```

So the result of the output is the integer currently pointed at but the pointer also get incremented. So the value printed is

```
1
2
```

not

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 3):

`++` has higher precedence than `*`, so your expression is equivalent to `*(pointer++)` -- it dereferences the value and then increments the pointer, not the value. If you want to increment the value, you need to do `(*pointer)++`.

Comment: The value is that pointed to before the (post-)increment. It doesn't increment the pointer and then return the new value pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same thing as doing

```
*(pointer++)
```

in that it increments the address that the pointer holds, *then* it dereferences it.

Comment: And that's also how it should be written, so there's no confusion.

Comment: @Ben: Perhaps, but it's debatable. Would you also recommend writing `a * b + c` as `(a * b) + c`? Or would you rely on a competent programmer to know the precendence rules?

Comment: @Stuart: I expect anyone reading my code to know the precedence rules which are the same regardless of language.  Which pretty much means mathematical precedence only.

Answer (score 1):

`*pointer++` means `*(pointer++)`.

i.e.,  it increments the pointer, not the pointee.

one way to remember that is to read the original K&R "The C Programming Language", where their example of `strcpy` uses this.

anyway, that's how i remember the precedence.

and since it increments the pointer, your second dereference has Undefined Behavior.

cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing the pointer's value, not the value pointed by it.